# Составление подробной документации о вашей сети

Tags: документация

Здравствуйте.

Вот решил в кучу собрать свои документы, которых невероятно много: о всех устройствах, да с анализами разными. Т.е. на данный момент у меня имеется гора различных документов, включающих базовые настройки, бекапы, описание шагов предыдущего траблшутинга и т.д.

Хочу собрать все это в один документ, упростить до чего возможно, чтобы в случае чего почти любой "продвинутый" пользователь мог найти решение хотя бы простейших проблем в мое отсутствие.

Более того хочется собрать в кучу т.н. Security Concept. Который даст некоторый уровень понимания, где у нас "узкие" места.

Немаловажным является то, чтобы такой "пакет" документов было как можно легче обновлять, дабы поддерживать его в актуальном состоянии.

Посему возник вопрос, как вы делаете это у себя на предприятии? Хочется услышать советы, работающие решения, для гетерогенных систем и предприятий с 50+ работников.

Спасибо заранее за ответы!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

База знаний DokuWiki. На стартовой странице - понятные ссылки в алфавитном порядке, типа "1С", "АТС", "Новый компьютер", "Принтеры", "Картриджи", "Wi-Fi" и т.д. На видном месте есть поиск. Права можно настроить - без авторизации только просмотр. Некоторые разделы можно закрыть от посторонних (пароли). Обновлять проще некуда. Таблицы и рисунки вставляются достаточно просто. Править можно с любого компа - пароль поменял и тут же задокументировал. Тему оформления можно без излишеств подобрать, у меня - Backpack. Использую в сети около 80 хостов. Доволен. Рекомендую.

Comment: аналогично, использовал dokuWiki. А вообще обычно предприятия используют для этих целей wiki.... какую именно -- это индивидуально. ;)

Comment: Как ни странно, тема актуальна до сих пор. Перебрал несколько решений wiki и тоже остановился на dokuwiki. Особенно интересно было решение для Joomla - там есть плагин Jfusion, который качественно интегрирует dokuwiki в сайт, используется не только шаблон сайта, но и синхронизируются пользователи. Очень удобно, как для внутреннего использования, так и для блога. К dokuwiki очень много плагинов, настроить можно под любые нужды практически без программирования.
dokuwiki можно [развернуть даже на флешке](http://lifehacker.com/5672325/dokuwiki-on-a-stick-packs-a-portable-wiki-in-a-tiny-package)